# element in a array contains double quotation

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to have ""apple"" as the element in the array as the output. The sad thing is it has to be in this kind of format.

But presto automatically added the escape character "/". (i.e "/"apple/"")

How do I get rid of it

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate your issue using DataGrip. Are you sure it's not your IDE auto-adding the escape character? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElMgW.png

Comment: You array should store exactly what you want - i.e. `"apple"`. This should be an "issue" of internal representation of string via presto/IDE - note that it is wrapped in double quotes, languages which use double quotes to represent strings (like Java which is used to write Presto) require double quotes inside the string to be escaped during input via string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two double quotes around the string apple ""apple""